# Modify a value in a specific line in a C file

Tags: c, file

I am making a project where I want to store some information inside a text file. I am able to read the data from the file but I do not know how to modify it and then save it. The program I am creating gives the user options to choose from. Each option represents a different car and has a specific price and amount remaining. What I'm trying to do is subtract 1 from the amount remaining of the car that the user has chosen.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

    // creating a file pointer and a variable holding the file's name
    FILE* fp;
    char fileName[] = "list.txt";
    
    // array to store amount of cars left
    int carsLeft [10] ;

    // array to store the brand of each car
    char carModel[10][150];

    // array to store the price of each car
    int carPrice[10];
            
    // opening the file     
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r+");

           
    // making sure the file is not empty            
    if (fp != NULL) {
               
        // this loop will not stop until the if condition is met to break it
        while (1) {
                   
            // scanning for our data from the file                  
            int scanResult = fscanf(fp, "%s %d,%d", &carModel[i], &carPrice[i], &carsLeft[i]);              
            i++;
                
            // if we reach the end of the file we end the loop            
            if (scanResult == EOF) {
              
                break;
            }
        }
  }
     scanf("%d", &usersChoice);

     // this is the modification I want to do in my txt file but I do not know how
     carsLeft [usersChoice - 1] -= 1;
}
```

The structure of my file goes like this:

```
AAAA 12345,12
BBBB 56789,34
```

My goal is to make the 12 change to 11.

Comment: Your modification code only modifies the `carsLeft` array - which is data that's in memory, not the data in the file. To modify data in the file you must _write_ to the file (and seek the appropriate position in the file at which to write). But to be honest - I doubt you really need to make this individual change in-place.

Comment: Yes, I understand that my code is not modifying the file. My issue is that I do not know how to locate the specific line I want and then set my pointer to the correct position to change the value. I have been programming for about 2 weeks and this is also my first programming language so I have very little knowledge.

Comment: Especially after only two weeks, it will be hard to modify one part of a text file in place. How would you deal with a price rise, from 9999 to 10000? Where would the extra digit be stored? The easy way is to read all the data, make any changes, and create another file.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how to locate the specific line I want and then set my pointer to the correct position to change the value.

Consider cases when the price is 1000 and the decremented value is shorter as text, shifting all remaining records.

Consider pathological case when case when the price is 0 and the decremented value is longer as text, shifting all remaining records.

Rather than find the correct position, simple re-write the file.

```
    // Read data 
    while (i < 10 && \\ 
        fscanf(fp, "%149s %d,%d", carModel[i], &carPrice[i], &carsLeft[i]) == 3) {
      i++;
    }

    // edit data
    scanf("%d", &usersChoice);
    carsLeft[usersChoice - 1] -= 1;

    // Save
    rewind(fp);
    for (int j = 0; j < i); j++) {
      fprintf(fp, "%s %d,%d", carModel[j], carPrice[j], carsLeft[j]);
    }

    // All done 
    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: "Simply rewrite the file" is often bad advice.

Comment: @einpoklum I look forward to your better complete alternative for OP who commented  "I have been programming for about 2 weeks".